# Gmail: How do I mute ALL coming mail *except* mail from certain senders?

Tags: notifications, gmail, mute

I have a gmail account and I am getting too many inbox notifications. It wouldn't work to create a blacklist, because they come from many places. I would like to whitelist 3 or 4 senders and only receive notifications from them. Thank you.

Comment: If Gmail app doesn't offer this feature, your best alternative would be to automatically get unwanted inbox notifications automatically cleared instantly. I suggest you look into automation app than. I don't use Gmail app so can't confirm, but I think MacroDroid app can exclude certain notifications from its notifications filter. That way, excluding certain senders of your choice pretty much all notifications would be dismissed.

Comment: I use the "open mail" app to access my gmail, but it is muted. To get beeps for specific mails, I forward the important messages to another account, and the beeps are doing by the "enotify" app. I do not use the gmail app.

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

1. whitelist a couple of email-addresses and mark them as *important*.
2. On the general tab of gmail settings choose: Important mail notifications on.

Hope this solves your issue.